# Kendo Charts for Angular: Line Chart gets cut off with set max value

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

When I set a maxvalue in a line chart, a point that matches this value gets cut off.

I tried adding a margin, but the margin is applied outside of the chart area.
I've been over the [API](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/), but to no avail.

The following plunker demonstrates the problem: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/ME0onobWse9eIZ8mAAxW?p=preview)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-chart>
          <kendo-chart-value-axis>
              <kendo-chart-value-axis-item [title]="{ text: 'Miles' }"
                                           [min]="0" [max]="100">
              </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
          </kendo-chart-value-axis>

          <kendo-chart-category-axis>
              <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="categories">
              </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
          </kendo-chart-category-axis>

          <kendo-chart-series>
            <kendo-chart-series-item [data]="seriesData" type="line">
            </kendo-chart-series-item>
          </kendo-chart-series>
        </kendo-chart>
    `
})
export export class AppComponent {
    public seriesData: number[] = [20, 40, 100, 30, 50];
    public categories: string[] = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

Apparently you can add a kendo-chart-pane where the standard enabled clip option can be disabled.

For anyone interested:

```
      <kendo-chart-value-axis>
          <kendo-chart-value-axis-item [title]="{ text: 'Miles' }"
                                       [min]="0" [max]="100" pane="pane">
          </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
      </kendo-chart-value-axis>
      <kendo-chart-panes>
          <kendo-chart-pane name="pane" clip="false">
          </kendo-chart-pane>
      </kendo-chart-panes>
```

Updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vMYXLfdoYexydyPoRINi?p=preview)